# Why the decrypted key is not same as encrypted key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I wrote a function to encrypt or to decrypt a word.
Why the decrypted key is not same as encrypted key?

```
function cryptage(action, password) {
    var method = "AES-256-CBC";
    if (action == "encrypt") {
        var cipher = crypto.createCipher(method, password)
        var crypted = cipher.update(password, 'utf8', 'hex')
        crypted += cipher.final('hex');
        return crypted;
    } else if (action == "decrypt") {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(method, password)
        decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(password, 'hex', 'utf8')
        decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

When I call `var crypted = cryptage("encrypt", "test")`, it returns

> cc1fbd73cb93106c3358636ff619bdbd

When I call `cryptage("decrypt", crypted)`, it returns exactly

> Te�~��IӠ~{ }m

but no text, Why ?

Comment: I did not review all your code, but if the second parameter of the function is `password` and you provide different values, it can never work

Comment: To "encrypt" something, you need a *secret* (e.g. password) and a plaintext. Your algorithm just accepts one value. That *cannot* be an encryption, it's an *encoding* at best.

Comment: No because there is a return, so only one value.

Comment: And the secret is var method = "AES-256-CBC";.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR => **R**ead **T**he **F**ine **M**anual

The nodejs crypto module expects you to provide 2 things when you create either a Cipher or Decipher instance via the 2 parameter overload of CreateCipher/CreateDecipher: a method - the name of the actual openssl cipher to use, and a password, which will be fed into EVP_BytesToKey and the result will be the keybytes for the actual cipher instance

a new implementation using this should inevitable lead to punishment for the autor by now... it is insecure and should be replaced by PBKDF2 for example... you would know this if you'd have read the documentation... but anyways ... you want to know why your function does not return the desired output ... the reason is simple ...

you provide the same value as password and data and upon decryption you want to provide the encryption result... this can not work

have a look at the simplified encryption and decryption function/formula

ENCRYPT(DATA,KEY) => CIPHERTEXT
DECRYPT(CIPHERTEXT,KEY) => DATA

this is pretty straight forward and is valid for all symetric ciphers (like AES, including all modes of operation and all keysizes, so... yes... even for AES with a 256 bit key in cipher-block-chaining mode)

so what's the matter in your case? you do this:
you declare key and data to be the same...
ENCRYPT(KEY,KEY) => CIPHERTEXT
DECRYPT(CIPHERTEXT,CIPHERTEXT) => GARBAGE

please note that for a successful decryption the key parameter for the encrypt and decrypt function **MUST** be the same, which fails for your case

so for your approach that would mean that you need the very same original password for decryption as the key parameter ... yes... you would need the very same value you want to decrypt ... as an input... to your decrypt function ...